# How to retrieve user data of authenticated users in Firebase Realtime Database with Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve profile data of the currently logged in user from Firebase Realtime Database. I have authenticated my users using email and password. I then saved the signup data on the database, as an object as follows: (All of this code is onCreate in SignUpActivity). I saved the data as **User** objects. My **User** model class has getters and setters, parameterized and blank constructors.

```
´´´´// Initialize FirebaseAuth and DatabaseReference
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    //save all data to database

                   String mUserId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        User user = new User(email, name,tel, address1,address2,user_type, mUserId);

                        //add to database
                        mDatabaseRef.child(mUserId).setValue(user);
//open main activity
Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thus, mUserId is the userId of authenticated users. My database structure is as follows, and the rules are default public.

```
wish-store-42facaddclose
    users
        2GbVFSMFrihqVJ8OAXBa56owNW93
            address1: "juja"
            address2:  "Town"
            email:  "a.bea@gmail.com"
            phone:  "+237638256239"
            userId:  "2GbVFSMFrihqVJ8OAXBa56owNW93"
            userName:  "Beatrice Njambi"
            userType:  "Buyer Account"
```

Now, to retrieve data in MainActivity, this is the code I’m using in onCreate:

```
//instantiate firebaseAuth
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then onStart;

```
userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userNameHeader);

//check to see if user is logged in
mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
    //the user is not logged in, start login activity
    loadLogInView();
} else {


    String mUserId = mFirebaseUser.getUid();

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = root.child("users").child(mUserId);

    ValueEventListener profileListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            userName.setText(user.getUserName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("Read failed", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(profileListener);


}
```

I had tried to debug, and it says there is a null pointer exception for **mUserId**. So, the problem is correctly referencing the *userId* of the authenticated users. Please help, I really don’t understand what I’m doing wrong.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Getting `mUserId ` in `SignUpActivity` ?

Comment: Can you add your exception log?

Comment: @ prosper K. I'm able to reference it in signUpActivity because the User object is successfully saved under the mUserId node.

Comment: If `mUserId` is null it means that you are not authenticated, right? So please make sure you are authenticated before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the `ValueEventListener` for the database object directly, rather than setting it later. Try to check if you have initialized the `FirebaseAuth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        String uId = mUser.getUid();
        String personName=mUser.getDisplayName();
        String personEmail=mUser.getEmail();
        String personPhoto=mUser.getPhotoUrl();
```

try this